# Disparity in the definitions of continuity at a point and interval

Tags: limits, continuity, differential

In trying to deeply understand continuity, I have found (to my limited knowledge) a disparity in the definitions of continuity at points and intervals.

By definition, a point is continuous if it’s left hand limit at x=a, right hand limit at x=a and f(a) are equal.

By definition, an endpoint is continuous if f(a) is equal to the limit which exists for that particular endpoint.

By definition, a function is continuous in an interval if the function is continuous at each point in the interval which in turn, is determined by the above definitions of continuity at points/endpoints.

Now, consider this diagram of a jump discontinuity:

[image: jump discontinuity]
We can state using the above definitions that f(x) is continuous in (- ∞, a] ∪ (a, ∞).

Combining the above ranges we can state that that f(x) is continuous in  (- ∞, ∞). But now, again using the same definitions f(x) is discontinuous in (- ∞, ∞).

What have I missed?

Comment: You have answered your own question.  Being continuous from the right on $(-\infty,a]$ is not the same thing as being continuous (fully).  You're taking the union of two sets of different continuity "types."

Comment: @Randall could you please explain this more formally by providing  better definitions to the terms defined in the question ?

Comment: I think the problem might be with "Combining the above ranges", in which you're taking the union of two functions. Note that $f:{\mathbb Q} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1$ is everywhere continuous and $g:({\mathbb R} - {\mathbb Q}) \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ defined by $g(x) = 0$ is everywhere continuous (note that each is a constant function), but their union $(f \cup g):{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ is discontinuous at each point in $\mathbb R.$ The union of two "nice" functions doesn't have to be "nice".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, for a function defined in $(-\infty, a]$, the limit at $x=a$ does not exist. We might thus make an extension of the definition of continuity to allow for continuity at the boundary. To do that, we demand instead that the left-handed limit is equal to $f(a)$, But note that this in an exception that is only made for points at the boundary. For every other point, we demand that both left and right-handed limits equal $f(a)$. Thus, when you consider the union $(-\infty, a]\cup(a,\infty)$ you cannot treat $a$ as an endpoint anymore. Since "continuity" at endpoints only demands side limits, you will end up with a function that has both a limit to the left of $a$ and a limit to the right of $a$, but they need not be equal.

Comment: I understand what you’re trying to say, but doesn’t that mean that the definitions are wrong/require addition ?

Comment: @ShashwatTomar well, I wouldn't call a definition "wrong" unless it is inconsistent, which I don't think is the case here.  It's only a matter of what you call a continuous function. If you want it to be continuous at each point of its domain then you can't call a function defined over $[a, \infty)$ continuous, since it doesn't have a limit at $a$. Intuitively, we think of continuous functions as not having "holes", or some abrupt changes in their values, which would not be the case for a function that is discontinuous at $a$ merely because there are no points at the right of this point.

Comment: Also, in some applications discontinuity at the interior of an interval is a problem, while not having a limit at an endpoint isn't. For example, in physics you might have  $x(t)$ defined over $[0,1]$, where $0$ and $1$ are the initial and final instants of the motion. Obviously, $x(t)$ isn't continuous at $t=0$, but that's irrelevant, as $0$ is just the instant we turned the clock on. If it if were discontinuous at $t=0.5$...well, we can't have that, it would be like teleportation.  So I wouldn't use the same name for these two situations, and would prefer to call the first one continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see where you are wrong is: You are considering continuity of 3 *different* functions. The function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous everywhere except at $a$. The function $f|(-\infty, a]$ is continuous everywhere (via extending the definition of continuity to endpoints) and so is the functions $f|(a, \infty)$. The function $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore, even if you write $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty, a] \cup (a, \infty)$, $a$ is not an endpoint of the domain. Hence, we can not use the extended continuity definition in this way and say that $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty, a]$, because it is not continuous at $a$, which is not an endpoint, the right-sided limit can be calculated and the limit at $a$ doesn't exist.

Small remark for clarity: Continuity in an interval means continuity in the domain at every point of the interval. Not continuity in that interval at every point of the interval.